# Where can I ask why some delivery apps are allowed to sell inappropiate content?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which Stack Exchange sites may I ask why some delivery apps like Rappi, or Zomato are able to sell alcohol products, when it seems to violate Google Play's authorised content?

> I have read [on Google Play's information center](https://play.google.com/about/restricted-content/inappropriate-content/#!?zippy_activeEl=tobacco-alcohol#tobacco-alcohol) that there is no way to sell or facilitate alcohol to our users, I don't know if it's legal to sell this type of product or not.
>
> Context: I have a food delivery app and I want to know if it is possible to sell this kind of product to my users because I have some shops interested on selling alcohol, but I don't want to because I don't know if this is allowed with the terms.
>
> I have opened other famous food delivery apps and they also sell tobacco and alcohol which makes me really doubt about this topic.
>
> **Please, don't get me wrong, I'm against selling this, but the business needs these products and I don't know how to handle it.**
>
> [Here](https://mobilesyrup.com/2020/03/26/order-alcohol-online-food-delivery-app-ontario/) is another source about my question; I don't really know if this is related to goverment or Google-specific policies.

Comment: @Glorfindel no, this isn't off-topic, it's a [site-recommendation] question which simply needs editing (which I'm currently doing).

Comment: Better I delete this question @Glorfindel ? I'm seeking for this help because I dont want to do something that could incur in some violations

Comment: We get a lot of people who ask blatantly off-topic questions on this site expecting to get their answer *here* for various reasons (usually because they follow a link here and not realize they've been directed to a different site), enough that we've made automated tools to handle them. Unfortunately, on-topic questions (e.g. site recommendations) can get mistakenly caught in them. (Explaining their comment.)

Comment: @GastónSaillén my apologies, because of the unusual formatting my mind didn't register the first sentence. I still have to get used to the new way of displaying quotes ...

Comment: No problem , thanks for the support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Law SE has some questions about specific ToSs such as:

- [Is it allowed to use the Spotify Web API for commercial projects?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/15383/5348)
- [What can Thingiverse do with my Things according to their Terms?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/4777/5348)
- [Does "personal, noncommercial use" preclude use of Pokemon GO "Lure Modules" to attract players to non-commercial events?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/11601/5348)

But! You need to make sure you’re [not asking for personal legal advice](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/222/5348) (where the answer would be “you need to hire a lawyer”).

Comment: Sorry but this does not answer my question, the links your provided are from a different perpective than the question I'm having

Comment: @GastónSaillén I think Laurel was just providing examples that are tangentially related to your question.

Comment: @GastónSaillén Those weren’t related to your question at all, they just serve as evidence of a precedent that similar questions (about Terms of Services) are accepted on Law (because they’re all about legal precedent there ).

Comment: Thanks a lot Laurel !